# JS next tab jump section

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple next and previous tab to move between "section". When you click the next tab the page moved down and skips the next "section" and goes the one after.

```
    var $sec = $("section");
$(".prev, .next").click(function() {
  var y = $sec.filter(function(i, el) {
    return el.getBoundingClientRect().top > 0;
  })[$(this).hasClass("next") ? "next" : "prev"]("section").offset().top;
  $("html, body").stop().animate({
    scrollTop: y
  });
});
```

```
      <div data-role="page" id="main">
        <section>
            <div id="home-section" class="section">
                <img src="images/welcome-homepage.jpg" />
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="about-section" class="section">
                <img src="images/about-us.jpg" />
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="service-charter-section" class="section">
                <img src="images/service-charter.jpg" />
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="testionials-section" class="section">
                <img src="images/about-us.jpg" />
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what's not working and what the expected behaviour is? Maybe put in a jsbin/jsfiddle as a demo

Comment: It looks like it skips two sections at a time, I'm guessing the author want's it to do one at a time.

Comment: Here is a link to my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wbrichwalker/e4t1n8qy/34/

@Bryan it shouldn't skip a section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. It does *not* account for current scroll position, i.e. if you scroll halfway down and hit next, it will continue in series from the last item clicked through.  It just makes an array of all sections positions and hops through that as you click prev / next.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var sectionPosition = 0;
  var scrollPositions = []

  function scroll(y) {
    $('html').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: y
    });
  }

  $("section").each(function(i, el) {
    scrollPositions.push(parseInt($(el).offset()['top']))
  })

  $(".prev, .next").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
      scroll(scrollPositions[sectionPosition + 1]);
      if (sectionPosition < scrollPositions.length) {
        sectionPosition++;
      }
    } else if (sectionPosition > 0) {
      scroll(scrollPositions[sectionPosition - 1]);
      sectionPosition--;
    }
  });
});
```